# Vertical Scroll Bar not showing in HTML

Tags: html

I'm having trouble getting a scroll bar to show for a school project. I've tried debugging, looking up different ways to fix this and trying all different types of codes. I, however, still can't get a scroll bar to show up.
Here's a preview of the code:

```html
<html>
<title>Cloud 9 HyperX</title>
<body background="test.png" alt="" style="position: fixed;>
<center><a href="http://na.lolesports.com/articles/power-rankings-6-cloud9"><img src="Cloud9.png" title="Power Rankings -- Cloud 9"></a><br></center>
<center><a href="http://na.lolesports.com/na-lcs/2015/spring/teams/cloud9">Cloud 9 LCS Page</a> || <a href="http://lol.gamepedia.com/Cloud9">Gamepedia</a>
<hr width=75% size=5 color=00aced>
<h1>Pro E-Sports Players, LCS Team</h1>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ts9dsDFkaQ0"><img src="C9team.png" title="Ultra Rapid Fire TSM vs C9"></a><br>
<p>Cloud 9 HyperX is a League of Legends Championship Series team consisting of<br>
<TABLE>
  <TABLE  BORDER="1">
   <TR>
      <TH COLSPAN="2">
      </TH>
   </TR>
      <TH>Name</TH>
      <TH>Role</TH>
   <TR>
      <TD>Hai "Hai" Lam</TD>
      <TD>Mid Laner</TD>
   </TR>
   <TR>
      <TD>An "Balls" Le</TD>
      <TD>Top Laner</TD>
   </TR>
   <TR>
      <TD>William "Meteos" Hartman</TD>
      <TD>Jungler</TD>
   </TR>
      <TR>
      <TD>Zachary "Sneaky" Scuderi</TD>
      <TD>ADC (Attack Damage Carry)</TD>
   </TR>
      <TR>
      <TD>Daerek "LemonNation" Hart</TD>
      <TD>Support</TD>
   </TR>
</TABLE>
<!--My favorite thing to do on the weekend is play video games with my friend Tim Fish and Jake McGraw and watch LCS-->
<p>Cloud 9, previously <a href="http://lol.gamepedia.com/Quantic_Gaming">Quantic Gaming</a>, first entered the LCS with the line-up of<br>
Nientonsoh(Team Fusion), Hai, LemonNation, WildTurtle(Team Solo Mid), <br>
and Yazuki. While Team Quantic they tried to enter the LCS qualifiers, <br>
but lost their first run. After their first lost in the LCS qualifiers,<br>
they took on a major roster change.<br></center>
<p align="left">
<ul>
<li>Yazuki left, Balls came in for top lane
<li>WildTurtle moved to TSM, Sneaky came in for ADC
<li>Neintonsoh left leaving mid open, Hai moved to mid from previously being jungle
<li>Meteos stepped into jungle to complete what was Quantic Gaming.<br>
</ul></p><center>
 After the roster change Quantic went through LCS qualifiers again, only this time<br>
 under the name of Cloud 9. After entering the LCS Cloud 9 won two LCS<br>
 seasons and finished in the top eight for Season 3 World Championship.<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove this declaration

```
style="position: fixed;
```

Your scrollbars will appear, when needed.

In general, and this is out of the scope of your question but, your markup has quite a few mistakes, just so you know. Maybe this can help you improve http://www.htmldog.com/guides/html/

Comment: Thanks! I actually fixed it on my own and realized I typed style instead bgproperties. I'm relatively new to HTML for full web pages so thanks for the help.